# High vs Low memory addresses and branching

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address

Can anyone explain me what does high vs low addresses mean in the context of the following question?:

By definition, “high” addresses are those that are large unsigned numbers and “low” addresses are those that are small unsigned numbers.

What is the highest address to which control can be transferred using a `beq` (branch on equal) instruction that resides at the physical memory address  `0x320ACB48`?

Comment: You may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950230/how-to-calculate-jump-target-address-and-branch-target-address/6954138#6954138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the particular MIPS chip and on its MMU (if any).

The valid addresses for 32-bit instructions are from 0 to 4GB-4. However, if the memory isn't present in the entire range or if there are memory-mapped devices or if you have virtual to physical address translation enabled, you will not be able to execute code at an arbitrary location at all or in a meaningful way.

If you transfer control to a location not backed up by memory, you execute garbage. The same applies to transferring control to a location that represents some memory mapped device's registers or data buffers.

If the page translation is set up in such a way that it restricts accesses to specific regions of addresses or disallows execution there, you cannot execute anything in those regions at all.

Now, there's also a limitation in `beq` in terms of how far in can transfer control from where it (`beq`) is located itself. `beq` can only transfer control to its location +/- approximately 2<sup>17</sup> bytes (=128KB).

So, in theory, `beq` located at 0x320ACB48 could transfer control to any location (that's a multiple of 4) from 0x320ACB48 + 4 - 32768*4 to 0x320ACB48 + 4 + 32767*4.

If `beq` is located near address 0, it may be able to transfer control to near 4GB, unless the CPU prohibits wrapping of addresses. Likewise, if `beq` is near the 4GB point, it may
be able to transfer control to near address 0, unless, again, address wrapping is prohibited by the CPU.

Comment: could you explain this sentence again: "in theory beq located at 0x320acb48 could transfer control to any location that is a multiple of 4". beq leaves us 16bits of offset so why isn't the highest memory address to which this instruction can transfer control to not 0x7fff or 32,767? I am having trouble understanding your logic.

Comment: @curiousX MIPS instructions (unless we're talking about extensions like microMIPS and MIPS16e) are 4 bytes long and always being on addresses that are a multiple of 4. There's no point in using the 16-bit offset as a byte offset, it would be a waste. So, the 16-bit offset in the branch instruction is multiplied by 4.