# JUMP instruction in MIPS

Tags: mips32

We express the target address in JUMP instruction only by 26 bits so this address becomes dependent on current PC+4 value. 
Consider the case when the instruction that I want to jump to is located in my code at

0010&[my_target = 26 bits]&00

but  instead we'll jump to the wrong address that starts with 0011 ( to 0011&[my_target =  26 bits]$00 ) because the PC was already incremented to such value that changed its 4th bit.

Is this case really possible?

If it is, how it can be solved?

Thanx

Comment: Related: [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this case really possible?

Yes, it is. Quoting from *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*:

> When the jump instruction is in the last word of a 256 MB
> region, it can branch only to the following 256 MB region containing the branch delay slot.

> If it is, how it can be solved?

Load the address you want to jump to into a register and then use the `jr` instruction.