# what is the range of Branch instruction in mips?

Tags: mips

So I have this question that say, `beq instruction`  is executing from `0x80000000` address, what is the lowest destination address you can reach.

the answer is `0x7ffe0004`, but I couldn't figure out how to get to this result. any help please?

Comment: A rather unrealistic hypothetical..   0x80000000 is in the kernel address space, and 0x7FFE0004 is in the user stack space.  (No branch in the kernel would try to do that.)  They should have chosen a normal user code-space address somewhere in the middle for the location of the `beq`, like 0x00500000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIPS jump and branch instructions range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442586/mips-jump-and-branch-instructions-range)

Comment: i got answer down below, this link didnt realy helped, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset is a 16-bit signed field, ranging from -32768 to +32767.  That offset is in words, so it is multipied by 4.  The PC will already have been advanced, so the new address is `PC + 4 + 4*offset`.  4 x 32768 is 0x20000.  0x80000000 + 4 - 0x20000 is 0x7ffe0004.