# Can help me with mips translating to binary?

Tags: mips

I don't understand how to translate a label. Anyone can give me a help

suppose we have the following code:

```
loop: 
    add $t2,$t2,$t1 
    addi $t2,$t2,4 
    sw $t2,4($s0) 
    bne $t2,20,loop 
    jr $ra
```

How translate to binary `bne $t2,10,loop` ?

Comment: That's the job of a program that's called *assembler*, which takes *assembly code* and translates it to machine *bytecode*. You normally don't do this by hand.

Comment: If you're doing it by hand, you need to count the number of bytes between the "bne" and the "loop:", and substitute that count in for the "loop" argument.

Comment: So given it's running 32-bit instructions, the value of in "loop" in `bne $t2,10,loop` should be -12. As in 4 bytes på line and 3 lines up. Find now information of the MIPS instructions [here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).. My guess would be that the binary would be something like: 0001 01ss sss0 1010 1111 1111 1111 0110.. I'm not sure about this though..

Comment: @Rapsefar No, the value should be -16 because lines to jump is counted from one line after the jump instruction. Also note that what will acutally stored in the opcode will be -4 because the value in opcode will be multiplied by 4 to calculate the distance to jump.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to note.

The branch offset is *always* calculated from the address of the branch + 4 (i.e. PC+4), so it is relative to the address of the `jr` instruction.

Since mips instructions must be aligned to a word [four byte boundary], the rightmost two bits of an instruction address will be [must *always* be] zero.

The mips architecture takes advantage of that by encoding a branch offset as a *word* offset (i.e. the byte offset is shifted right by 2). This extends the range of a branch instruction 16 bit immediate encoding to 18 bits.

So, here is the listing:

```
00:     loop:
00:         add     $t2,$t2,$t1
04:         addi    $t2,$t2,4
08:         sw      $t2,4($s0)
0C:         bne     $t2,20,loop
10:         jr      $ra
```

The `jr` address is `0x10`, so the byte offset for loop would be -0x10 and the encoded offset would be -0x04 or 0xFFFC and the `bne` would be `xxxxFFFC`

But ... There is a problem with that. This particular `bne` uses an *immediate* value for the second argument. This makes the `bne` a pseudo-op and *not* a simple `bne` instruction.

So, the actual sequence becomes:

```
00:     loop:
00:         add     $t2,$t2,$t1
04:         addi    $t2,$t2,4
08:         sw      $t2,4($s0)
0C:         addi    $at,$zero,20
10:         bne     $at,$t2,loop
14:         jr      $ra
```

Note that the `bne` becomes a two instruction sequence: `addi` and `bne`

The `jr` address is now `0x14`, so the byte offset for loop would be -0x14 and the encoded offset would be -0x05 or 0xFFFB and the `bne` would be `xxxxFFFB`

The `bne` assembler format is:

```
    bne    s,t,label
```

The `bne` encoding is:

```
0001 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

So, the `s` register is `$at` or `$1` --> `00001`

The `t` register is `$t2` or `$10` --> `01010`

So, now we have:

```
0001 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
       00 0010 1010
0001 0100 0010 1010 iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

In hex, this is `142Ayyyy`. We already know that `yyyy` is `FFFB`, so the final hex value is: `142AFFFB`

Answer (score 0):

Branch on not equal has the syntax `bne rs,rt,label` where the first 6 digits is the opcode, the next 5 digits is the rs, the next 5 digits is the rt and the rest is the label of the branch target address:

`BTA = PC + 4 + imm * 4`

which is calculated by sign extending the immediate, multiplying by 4 and adding that and 4 to the program counter. For an explaination see this question

[How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950230/how-to-calculate-jump-target-address-and-branch-target-address)

The `bne` format is immediate (I-type). The opcode is 5 (000101). For example, this machine code prints every third character in the alphabet.

```
00100100000100000000000000110000
00000000000100000010000000100001
00100100000000100000000000001011
00000000000000000000000000001100
00100010000100000000000000000011
00100100000010000000000001011101
00010110000010001111111111111010
00000000000000000000000000000000
00001000000100000000000000001000
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

It is 10 lines (10 instructions). Line 7 is a branch and it has machine code `00010110000010001111111111111010`. The first 6 numbers `000101` is the opcode 5. Then 5 + 5 bits of registers (in this example the registers are $16 and $8 and the rest is the immediate branch target address.

Similarly, your program

```
.text
loop: 
    add $t2,$t2,$t1 
    addi $t2,$t2,4 
    sw $t2,4($s0) 
    bne $t2,20,loop 
    jr $ra
```

translates to 7 lines the machine code:

```
00000001010010010101000000100000
00100001010010100000000000000100
10101110000010100000000000000100
00100000000000010000000000010100
00010100001010101111111111111011
00000011111000000000000000001000
```

The actual translation looks like this

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x01495020  add $10,$10,$9        3        add $t2,$t2,$t1 
0x00400004  0x214a0004  addi $10,$10,0x00000004        addi $t2,$t2,4 
0x00400008  0xae0a0004  sw $10,0x00000004($16)5        sw $t2,4($s0) 
0x0040000c  0x20010014  addi $1,$0,0x00000014 6        bne $t2,20,loop 
0x00400010  0x142afffb  bne $1,$10,0xfffffffb      
0x00400014  0x03e00008  jr $31                7        jr $ra
```

...where the second to last line is the `bne` : `00010100001010101111111111111011` . The first 6 digits `000101` is the opcode, the next 5 (`00001`) + 5 (`01010`) digits are the registers and the rest (`1111111111111011`) is the immediate value of the branch target address (in hexadecimal `1111111111111011`=`FFFB`.

For more details see a [MIPS manual](https://www.kth.se/social/files/54948c82f276540590491ed4/mips-ref-cheat-sheet.pdf).