# Target address encoding for J-Type instructions in assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address, machine-code

According to my class notes, in MIPS, the encoding for a jump instruction is 6 bits for the opcode and 26 bits for the target address. But the addresses are 32 bits, so what part of the addresses are left out? Consider a `j` instruction (opcode 2 -> `000010` on 6 bits) and the target address `0x00400024` -> `0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0010 0100`. The final encoding is supposed to be `0x08100009`, and I really don't understand how the target address was encoded

Comment: Since instructions are aligned to 4 bytes, the two low bits are omitted. Given that `0x400024 >> 2 = 0x100009` that will be the encoding. Any instruction set reference should have told you this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the reference sheet I have did not mention that. It only said that 26 bits were used for the address.

Answer (score 1):

The *absolute* 32bit jump target address in MIPS is decoded by taking the highest 4bits of the address in the branch delay slot ( PC+4 ) and combining that with the 26bit `instr_index` field of the encoded `J` type instruction shifted left 2 bits. ( As @jester noted, this works because all jump target addresses must be 4byte aligned. )

To encode a jump target you take the low 28bits of the target address and shift right 2bits.

```
// Decoding a jump target.
TARGET := ((PC+4) & 0xF0000000) | (INSTR_INDEX << 2);

// Encoding a target.
INSTR_INDEX := (TARGET & 0x0FFFFFFF) >> 2;
```

Comment: Are you sure about it being region-relative to the branch-delay slot, rather than the J / JAL itself?  http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html shows a decoding formula of `PC = nPC; nPC = (PC & 0xf0000000) | (target << 2);` (nPC being "next PC", I assume, i.e. it's showing that the jump happens after running the branch-delay instruction, but that it's calculated with the high bits of the J / JAL itself.) [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230) and other SO answers agree

Comment: @PeterCordes The official documentation from MIPS Technologies states that _"The remaining upper bits are the corresponding bits of the address of the instruction in the delay slot (not the branch itself)"_.

Comment: @Michael: ah, then it's all the other answers that probably need updating.  That does make more sense that PC+=4 happens first, as always.