# Memory layout, does text segment have a max size?

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-layout

I saw a picture in "Computer Organization and Design":
[image: memory layout]
I am not sure whether the start address of static data segment “0x10000000” is just a example or a convention.

If the latter, does it represent that, the text segment has a max size of 0x10000000 - 0x00400000? And if so, how to load a executable file larger than this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a convention that was obeyed by software for the MIPS family of precessors, introduced in 1985. I don't think the addresses are valid for any current CPU architecture.

And you're right, the text segment has a max size of 0x10000000 - 0x00400000, meaning about 250 MByte. In 1985 that was so huge nobody could imagine larger program executables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So today (x86/x64 with Linux or Windows), is there still a convention for the start address of each segment? I guess operating system will determine the start addresses according to the segment size which are written in the header of executable file. But I failed to confirm it.

Comment: @Yriuns: MIPS `jal` (jump-and-link, function call) can only jump within the 256 MiB aligned region of address-space that contains the instruction after the `jal`.  [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230) .  So a limit of 256 MiB makes a ton of sense on MIPS, but zero sense on x86-64 where relative `call` and `jmp` have a range of +- 2GiB (purely relative, not absolute within an aligned region.)  Also not on AArch64 or ARM, or RISC-V; those have their own limits on call range.