# MIPS Counting Number of 1's given a user input (B instruction doesn't jump in MARS)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I wrote a code in MIPS that I thought would take in a users input (decimal number), AND it with 1 and increment this by 1 and shifting the bit position left by 1 until the number reached 0, then display the number of 1s in the decimal number in its binary representation. I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
# Count number of 1s in a 32 Bit Number
#$t0 = user input
#$t1 = counter
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter Number: "
result: .asciiz "Number of 1s counted: "
n:  .word   0
counter:.word   0
    .text

#Prompt User for Number 
    li $v0, 4       #load text stored in v0
        la $a0, prompt  #print prompt
        syscall     #call prompt string

#Get user Input   
        li $v0, 5   #load number stored in v0
        la $t0, n   #load int into $t0
        syscall     #display integer

#Store user input in $t0 to do function
        move $t0, $v0   #Move value from $v0 to $t0 to modify
        la $t1, counter #load address of counter
        lw $t1, 0($t1)  #load counter to t1

AND:
    andi $t2, $t0, 1 #and user input($t0) with 1 and store in $t2
    beq  $t2, 1, loop #if t2 equals 0 branch
    srl  $t0, $t0, 1 #shift user input($t0) to right 1 position logically
    b AND       #branch this function

loop:
    add $t1, $t1, 1 #add 1 to the counter
    srl $t0, $t0, 1 #shift $to to the right 1 position logically with counter
    beqz $t0, display #If $t0 equals 0 send to display function
    b AND       #send back to AND function if not

display:
       li $v0, 4    #load text stored in v0
       la $a0, result   #print text from address a0
       syscall
       la $a0, ($t1)    #load the address of the counter to a0
       li $v0, 1      #load integer stored in v0
       syscall        #print final integer
```

Comment: you're doing so many unnecessary memory loads and stores. There are still lots of free registers, just use them

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through this code with MARS 4.5 MIPS emulator reveals that for some yet unknown reason for me `b AND` just does not work as should. If you write `j AND` instead everything will work correctly.

**EDIT:** As @Peter Cordes pointed out it is most likely an assembler bug.

**NOTE:** You could remove the whole `loop` part and do this in the `AND` section:

```
and:
    andi $t2, $t0, 1 #and user input($t0) with 1 and store in $t2
    add $t1, $t1, $t2 #add the result it is either 0 or 1
    srl  $t0, $t0, 1 #shift user input($t0) to right 1 position logically
    beqz $t0, display #If $t0 equals 0 send to display function
    j and       #send back to AND function if not
```

Comment: MIPS branch instructions use *signed* relative displacements; they can branch backwards.  `bgez $zero, target` is a pretty normal way for MIPS to encode a relative branch-always, like `beq $zero, $zero, target` reaching +/-128kB relative to PC+4.  [MIPS jump and branch instructions range](//stackoverflow.com/q/36442586).  Are you sure changing `b` to `j` changed the program's output?  Did you maybe use a different test input that didn't exercise whatever bug the OP has? 
 (like high bit set or cleared, or low bit set or cleared, in case there's a problem on the first or last iteration.)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I did not changed anything on the input test input. You could verify this by downloading MARS 4.5. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure that MIPS relative branches can go forward and backward.  What exactly did you see that was wrong in MARS?  Unlike real MIPS, it doesn't simulate branch-delay slots by default, but that's an option.

Comment: It resolves the labels to their hex values but it does not did it with `b AND` and also it is just gone past it simply.

Comment: Yeah, I see the same thing in MARS myself; that's an assembler bug.  Notice that the low 16 bits of the branch encoding is `FFFF`, i.e. jump to the branch-delay slot.  If you enable delayed branching (which breaks the code), the branch-delay slot executes twice.  Once as the delay slot, once as the branch target.

Comment: Ohh, nice catch. Thats a shame I started to like this emulator..

Comment: It's generally pretty good.  One of the main downsides I knew of before this bug were that it didn't support %hi(symbol) and %lo(symbol), so if you want to lui/lw yourself you'd have to hard-code numeric addresses.

Comment: Yes I like it anyway so I stick with it too, but good to know these bugs! o7

Answer (score 1):

**MARS apparently has an assembler bug on `b` instructions when the label name is also a valid instruction mnemonic**.  It ends up as a branch-to-next instruction.

**Changing the label name from `AND` to `AND_TOP` made it assemble correctly.**  Eraklon found that using a `j` instruction also worked.  (The `:` instead of operands disambiguates the token as being a label instead of an instruction, so **this is a bug in MARS, not a bug in your code.**  clang assembles your source code just fine.  Not that you could run it outside of MARS; it depends on MARS system calls and no-delay-slot branches.)

I tested in Mars 4.5 under Java OpenJDK 1.8.0_232 on Arch GNU/Linux and reproduced @Eraklon's result.  (But the reasoning in that answer is wrong.)

Both `b AND` instructions assemble to `0x043fFFFF` (with listed instruction `bgez $0, AND`), so **the branch target is the instruction right after the branch**.  (What would be the delay slot on real MIPS).  [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950230/how-to-calculate-jump-target-address-and-branch-target-address) shows that MIPS relative-branch instructions are I-type, and sign-extend the 16 bit immediate (the low 16 of the instruction word) and left-shift by 2.  (Or look at it unshifted as an offset in words).  Relative to the end of the branch-delay slot.  So an offset of `-1` gets us to the instruction after the branch.

**Also note that `0x043f` is not the right opcode and register encoding for `bgez`**.  It should be `0x0401` for `bgez $zero`.  (http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html shows encodings in binary).  According to `llvm-objdump -d` (after assembling `.word 0x043fffff` with `clang -target mips`), that actually encodes `4 3f ff ff   synci -1($1)`.  I wonder if the MARS bug was ORing in a `-1` value that was wider than it should have been, overwriting some higher bytes?

(`bgez $0` is one way to encode an unconditional relative branch in MIPS.  Another way is `beq $0,$0, target`.  There's no separate opcode, you just have to pick one of the I-type `b...` machine instructions with inputs that are always true.)

**MARS *simulates* this mis-assembled instruction as a branch-always with the offset it encoded: it effectively falls through the branch**.  Or with Settings->Delayed Branching enabled, the instruction after the branch executes twice: once as the delay slot, once as the branch target.

So apparently the simulator doesn't truly decode from machine code, even if you turn on settings->self modifying code.  Or it's just the display that's broken?  IDK, doesn't really matter, this is 100% a bug and instead of poking at the symptoms someone should just look at the MARS source and fix it.

---

**Using a different label name gives correct results: the first `b AND_TOP` assembles to `0x0401fffb`**, with MARS listing it as `bgez $0, 0xfffffffb`.  (Note the numeric offset in the listing, instead of the AND label name.)

And it simulates correctly, with those branches going to the right place.

---

I didn't check your logic but it seems over-complicated.  Note that `la $a0, ($t0)` is an insane way to write `move $a0, $t0`.  Apparently MARS allows that.  There was no reason to load from `counter` in the first place, though; you can zero a register with `addu $t0, $zero, $zero` or whatever else you want.  Or write it as `move $t0, $zero`.

Also this is silly:

```
    beqz $t0, display #If $t0 equals 0 send to display function
    b AND_TOP         #send back to AND function if not

display:
```

Just `bnez AND_TOP` instead of conditionally jumping over an unconditional branch.

Also, neither comment adds anything to the understanding.  If there's something to say about *why* you jump, or the *semantic* meaning (e.g. in terms of high-level variables, not register names), then put that in a comment.  e.g. `bnez $t0, count_loop   # more bits left to count?`

Of course, as @Eraklon points out, your whole branching logic is super over-complicated.  Just isolate the low bit and add it to the count whether it's zero or one.

Or if you care about performance, mask away even and odd bits, right shift by 1, and addu.  Then you have 16x 2-bit accumulators packed into a register.  Repeat with another mask until you have bytes, then either keep going or use a multiply trick to get bytes summed into the high byte.  (See fast popcount Q&As here on stack overflow for bithack answers, or https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel.  Your method is like https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive but more complicated.  There are middle-ground options, e.g. clearing the lowest set bit and counting iterations to make it zero.)