# Why does MIPS use 'PC+4' as base address when calculating branch target address?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, machine-code

If you observe the MIPS 5-stage pipeline (1.Instruction Fetch - 2.Instruction Decode - 3.Execute - 4.Memory Access - 5.WriteBack), whether to branch or not is finally determined at Execute stage.
[image: MIPS 5-stage pipeline]

You can see in the image that the upper output of ALU is fed into a MUX to choose between normal PC step and branch.

Hence, when the CPU decides whether to branch, two pipeline stages have passed from the IF stage of corresponding instruction. Suppose **PC1 = PC when IF** and **PC2 = PC when decides to branch**. Hence **PC2 = PC1+4**. In order to revert **PC2** to **PC1+4**, additional hardware is required. (for operation **PC2-4**)

In spite of this disadvantage, I wonder why does the MIPS processor uses **PC+4** as base address rather than using **PC+8** as it is?

Comment: Instructions are 4 bytes long, so PC+4 is the next instruction that would be executed with no branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything you'd need more hardware to get PC+8, or it would complicate exception-return handling and stuff even more if you were thinking you could skip the pipeline stages and have the branch offset apply to the value of the fetch-stage address.  (MIPS branch delay slots mean that returning from an exception needs a PC and separate next-PC in case the branch delay slot from a taken branch faulted.)

Also what if fetch stalls and doesn't advance PC?

In actual classic MIPS, [branch latency is 1 cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58601958/224132) so it makes sense that branches are relative to the instruction in the branch-delay slot not 2 instructions later; [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230).

Also, the IF stage has already computed PC+4 so it can send that value down the pipeline along with the instruction.  You don't want long wires if you can avoid it; it makes sense to send the PC+4 value through the latches between pipeline stages.

Comment: (I'm not 100% certain that it made sense back in the early 80's to send PC+4 through the latches of pipeline stages: clock frequencies were *much* lower, so wire delays were much less significant than in modern CPUs.  Saving transistors with fewer latches would be a win if you can avoid needing PC+4 in later stages.  classic MIPS I doesn't have PC-relative addressing modes, for example.)