# Explain Long (Far) Jumps in a Data Path, and what Control Signals are Associated

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I am currently taking a Computer Architecture class, and I have a test coming up soon, on that test one of the many things I'm going to need to know is how to find the control signals for a long (far) Jump (likely using a hypothetical MIPS instruction), however I hardly know the difference between a long and a regular jump.
I believe that in a long jump you're attempting to jump to an address that's too large of a distance away to store it's address in a register so you need a storage specifically for the address, what would this look like on a data path? And which control signals would be used in this process?

If anyone would offer an explanation I would be very grateful, and if it helps here is the image of the data path we have been using in my class:
[image: Data_Path]

Comment: MIPS has "branches" and "jumps".  MIPS does not use terms of long/far/regular/short jumps (though other processors do).  Each of branch & jump are supported by specific opcodes in a non-hypothetical MIPS.  If you're using a hypothetical MIPS processor/instruction, how are we supposed to help?  I would suggest you get more detail about what that instruction is and does.

Comment: (FYI, it is extremely unlikely that there's a distance too large for a register, especially as register-based jumps use absolute addresses rather than pc-relative deltas.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Erik! I will see if I can find any relevant examples of a MIPS instruction.

Comment: If I had to guess at what a "long jump" would be in MIPS, I'd guess that instead of leaving the upper 4 bits of PC unmodified, it would maybe left-shift the immediate more, so it can target a 64-byte aligned address anywhere in memory.  (Low 6 bits = 0).  [How to Calculate Jump Target Address and Branch Target Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230)

Comment: This datapath diagram doesn't have any support for MIPS jumps, only MIPS branches (which are conditional, and with 16-bit immediate).  Looks like it would have to be extended for jumps with wider immedate.